# PHP not loading http.so

Tags: php, macos, pecl-oauth

I updated my Mac to OS X Mavericks (10.9) and have had to setup PHP again, along with PECL OAuth.

When I verify my install with the command php -v, I am getting an error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so, 9): Symbol not found: _php_persistent_handle_abandon
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38)

Has anyone else come across this? Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 12):

I worked it out....had to install pecl_http-1.7.6.

```
# 1. Uninstall the current version with this command:
pecl uninstall pecl_http

# 2. Install an older version, at least until latest is figured out on Mac OSX 10.8+
pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
```

Comment: i have this same issue but i have no idea with version of pecl_http I have nor do I know how to upgrade. I tried `sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` but that didnt seem to help

Comment: @numerical25: Don't worry about what version you have, running the uninstall command will remove whatever you have installed. Then just add a version, like above, that will work for you needs.

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this issue by editing php.ini.

My `pecl install pecl_http` mixed it up and put few `extension=` lines on top of my php.ini in wrong order. The `http.so` has to be below `propro.so` and `raphf.so` according to [dependencies](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http#Dependencies:).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the installation indeed bloats out the ini configuration and need to be fixed manually.