# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so Mac Maverick

Tags: php, apache, oauth-2.0, pecl-oauth

For some reason my PHP CLI is not picking up my http.so file. I am on Mac Maverick. When I check my the directory `'/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so'` I can see the file and I remember installing pecl_http. I also tried changing permissions and that didnt seem to help. Any Suggesions ???

[image]

[image]

the error message reads...

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so, 9): Symbol not found: _php_persistent_handle_abandon
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so, 9): Symbol not found: _php_persistent_handle_abandon
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/http.so in Unknown on line 0
```

Here is the directory where the file is at

[image]

When I try to do a pecl `install pecl_install`
[image]
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920336/php-not-loading-http-so may or may not be relevant